# AttributeError: type object 'ChatConsumer' has no attribute 'as_asgi()

Tags: documentation, django-channels

```py
from django.urls import re_path
from . import consumers
websocket_urlpatterns = [
        re_path(r'ws/chat/(?P<room_name>\w+)/$',consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),]
```

getting error of `as_asgi()`

Comment: Please provide more description of your issue and what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 11):

This is because of the version of 'channels'. check the channels version of your channels. It is working with channels 3.0.1. If you had downgraded your channels-redis, channels also will get downgraded.

Answer (score 2):

Use `channels==3.0.1` & you are good to go.